# php or jquery code to update drag and drop sortable according to category

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have the following table:

```
news(id,cat_id,headline,sub_top_priority)
```

I create drag and drop sortable list.

It change the sub_top_priority column order in database.

The code works fine and also updating the order in database.

**But this will affect and change the order of all row in database.**

**But i need this to change order of sub_top_priority column according to category.**

**If category is different then it does not change order.**

plz suggest me...how to apply condition in update query.

**row display code**

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000; float:left; width:400px; padding:5px 4px 5px 4px; height:225px">
                <div id="contentLeft1">
                <ul>            
                <?php                  
                foreach($sub_top_select as $sub_top)
                {                       
                ?>
                <li id="recordsArray1_<?php echo $sub_top['id']; ?>"><?php echo $sub_top['headline']; ?></li>
                <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


<!--SCRIPT TO UPDATE SUB-TOP SECTION UP-DOWN OR DRAG AND DROP OPERATION IN DATABASE.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                          
    $(function() {
        $("#contentLeft1 ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&change=updatesubtop'; 
            $.post("add_status_news.php", order, function(theResponse){
                $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
            });                                                              
        }                                 
        });
    });

}); 
</script>
```

**page name add_status_news.php**

**php code to update order in database.**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['change']))
    {   
        $change = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change']); 
        $updateRecordsArray1 = $_POST['recordsArray1'];
        if ($change == "updatesubtop")
        {           
            $listingCounter1 = 1;
            foreach ($updateRecordsArray1 as $recordIDValue1)
            {       
                $query1 = "UPDATE news SET sub_top_priority = " . $listingCounter1 . " WHERE id = " . $recordIDValue1;              
                mysql_query($query1) or die($query1."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                $listingCounter1 = $listingCounter1 + 1;
            }           

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Er, ... WHERE cat_id = x ? But this seems to update all rows sequentially (or am I mis-reading it)? Surely you just want to update all rows (within the given category) which are greater than or equal to the target 'id' (position)

Comment: yes iwant to update all rows with in same category...plz help to change code...

Comment: I think I'd just re-read the drag-drop tutorials. I imagine that these issues would be covered either within the main body of the tutorials, or in the comments.

Comment: Googling, all the examples I've seen so far execute the UPDATE inside the loop. This is obviously inefficient. Build the UPDATE in the loop and then execute it outside the loop! Actually, an INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement would probably work better.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but I want to take advantage of the answer window's formatting options:

Instead of UPDATE, consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, sort_order INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (id,sort_order) VALUES ('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('D',4),('E',5);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+
| id | sort_order |
+----+------------+
|  A |          1 |
|  B |          2 |
|  C |          3 |
|  D |          4 |
|  E |          5 |
+----+------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (id,sort_order) VALUES ('A',5),('B',4),('C',3),('D',2),('E',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sort_order = VALUES(sort_order);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+
| id | sort_order |
+----+------------+
|  A |          5 |
|  B |          4 |
|  C |          3 |
|  D |          2 |
|  E |          1 |
+----+------------+
```

This has the advantage that the query can be built inside the loop and then executed outside the loop. On large lists, I suspect that this will be faster than endless round trips to the database.